# How I create this jquery in a reusable way?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using `Bootstrap` `popover`s with dynamic contents from my databese. In php, its creating dynamic classes for each `popover`. My question is, In jquery, do I need to call to triggering the popover separately?

This is how I use jQuery to trigger the popovers -

```
$(".image-info-popover-1").popover({
        html : true, 
        placement : 'left',
        trigger: 'hover',
        content: function() {
            return $('.popoverContent-1').html();
        },
        title: function() {
            return $('.popoverTitle-1').html();
        }
}); 

$(".image-info-popover-2").popover({
        html : true, 
        placement : 'left',
        trigger: 'hover',
        content: function() {
            return $('.popoverContent-2').html();
        },
        title: function() {
            return $('.popoverTitle-2').html();
        }
});

$(".image-info-popover-3").popover({
        html : true, 
        placement : 'left',
        trigger: 'hover',
        content: function() {
            return $('.popoverContent-3').html();
        },
        title: function() {
            return $('.popoverTitle-3').html();
        }
}); 

$(".image-info-popover-4").popover({
        html : true, 
        placement : 'left',
        trigger: 'hover',
        content: function() {
            return $('.popoverContent-4').html();
        },
        title: function() {
            return $('.popoverTitle-4').html();
        }
}); 

$(".image-info-popover-5").popover({
        html : true, 
        placement : 'left',
        trigger: 'hover',
        content: function() {
            return $('.popoverContent-5').html();
        },
        title: function() {
            return $('.popoverTitle-5').html();
        }
});
```

But this is not the best way If I have a list of popovers to triggering out. So anybody tell me the good way to do this in a reusable manner?

Thank you.

Comment: Well immediately you can reduce repition with a loop (be careful about closure of the iterating variable). I don't know what the `this` value is in popover functions, but you may be able to make it completely generic by looking up the indices by getting attributes from `this`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want it be reusable, I'd put it in a function which takes a number as a parameter. Your function could look like this

```
var popover_func = function(n) {
    $(".image-info-popover-"+n).popover({
        html : true, 
        placement : 'left',
        trigger: 'hover',
        content: function() {
            return $('.popoverContent-'+n).html();
        },
        title: function() {
            return $('.popoverTitle-'+n).html();
        }
    });
};
```

You should be able to call this using a for-loop

```
for (var i=0; i<=5;i++) {
    $(document).ready(popover_func(i));
}
```

Comment: how do I call this function?